# How to display the value returned by avg function (mysql) in angular

Tags: json, angularjs, angular

After executing a query, I received the following data which is in Json format which is in myDocData:

```
 data: [
    RowDataPacket {
      updatedAt: 2020-01-03T18:30:00.000Z,
      email: 'charles@hotmail.com',
      name: 'charles',
      money_spent: 1,
      'avg(e.money_spent)': 1
    },
 RowDataPacket {
      updatedAt: 2020-01-11T18:30:00.000Z,
      email: 'ank@gmail.com',
      name: 'ank',
      money_spent: 10,
      'avg(e.money_spent)': 6
    }
]
```

angular code:

```
<table   class="content-table" >
<thead>
 <tr>
 <th>EMAIL</th>
  <th>NAME</th>
  <th>money spent</th>
  <th>UPDATED</th>

  <th>AVERAGE</th>
</tr>

</thead>


  <tbody>
  <tr *ngFor="let item of myDocData">
    <td>{{item.email}}</td>
    <td>{{item.name}}</td>
    <td>{{item.money_spent}}</td> 
    <td>{{item.updatedAt}}</td>  


    <td>{{item.avg(e.money_spent)}}</td>


  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Issue is that I am unable to display the value given by avg function
(other attributes are displayed correctly).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the line:

```
<td>{{item.avg(e.money_spent)}}</td>
```

to:

```
<td>{{item['avg(e.money_spent)']}}</td>
```

In JS, you can use square bracket notation to get properties of objects.

Answer (score 0):

1. If you have the control over the back-end code then you can change the query which is returning `"avg(e.money_spent)"` to `"avg(e.money_spent)  as  avg_money_spent"` in this way will not be facing the issue and you can access the value using 
   `<td>{{item.avg_money_spent}}</td>`
2. Or you could also use the previous answer by @Viqas